# Creating a fragment behind the scenes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

One feature of my app was to export charts to PDF format. I used to have an export button on the chart fragment to do this. It was pretty straigtforward, simply called

```
chart.draw(canvas)
```

using the chart View onto the canvas of the pdf page.

But since I have added other exporting formats I have moved the export button away from this fragment and into a more generic place. Now I could theoretically setup just the chart view, but the entire fragment containing the chart view has quite complex logic for setting up the state of the chart view. So my idea was to just create the fragment with the same data and let it setup the state itself and then I can just grab the chart view and draw to the canvas. To do this I tried

```
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.instance)
        withContext(uiDispatcher) {
            chartFrag = Archive()
            val v = chartFrag!!.onCreateView(inflater, null, null)
            chartFrag!!.setID(setID, ChartType.TYPE1)
            chartFrag!!.onViewCreated(v!!, null)
        }
        val chart = chartFrag!!.chart
```

Then using the chart with the same PDF creation code as before. All my text is created on the pdf still fine so the creation of the PDF is fine, it is just the creation of the chart view that is not working.

My best guess would be maybe I can't call with null as a container, or maybe is it not drawn due to not being a part of the draw cycle.

I also tried doing

```
v!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
v!!.invalidate()
```

Any ideas? I think it would be a bad UX if it transitioned to the chart fragment quickly just to grab the view.

EDIT: I have gotten it working somewhat, I do what I posted earlier, then grab the view, remove it from the parent view and add it to the current view then wait for it to appear(using delay(2000)) and then I can do chart.draw(canvas). So is there no way of using View.Draw(Canvas) unless the view is visible? How else could I handle this?

EDIT2: Using the above EDIT I was able to change the views Visibility to Invisible and it still gets drawn to the canvas but never shows up on the screen. So still not a great solution, but it visibly works just as good as a perfect solution. The only other way I could think of doing this was to get a detatched Fragment in a valid state which I don't think there is any way of doing. With my understanding the only way to have a valid view that can draw to a canvas would be to have it inside of a layout and every layout has to be contained by something.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a Fragment at all, but a separate class that is responsible for the chart logic.

Comment: I essentially do, I created an abstract class inheriting from Fragment() which implements all of the charting logic which more specific types of charts inherit from. Realistically it could be made to be an interface, but all the classes that inherit will be Fragments, so its nice to pass around the abstract chart class and you can still use the Fragment() methods and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using post to ensure your view is loaded before you star drawing?

Like this:

```
view.post(
     chart.draw(canvas)
)
```

Comment: if you mean the variable "view" is what I have labelled as "v" I didn't try that, but if post() waits for it to be drawn I don't think the Fragment will ever because it is created in a detatched state with no parent and therefore will not get put into the correct state. From looking through the fragment class a lot of the functions required to set it up are private or protected(regular setup between starting a transition to a Fragment and viewDidLoad()). I came up with a decent solution I will edit in the post, but a cleaner solution would be great still.